# Facebook page tab app not showing

Tags: facebook, tabs, html, development-environment

I have the following problem. I create my page tab app in https://developers.facebook.com and switched the app to "public" showing the green light. This way my app should be searchable in facebook, but whatever I type, I can't find it. It doesn't show.
I know that submitting for review is only needed when you want your app to be listed in app store, but if you need it to just be searchable, making it "public" by ticking the button at Status&Review should be done.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need 10 MAU according to the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas#search

before your app is indexed in the search.

> When your app exceeds 10 monthly active users it will be automatically queued to be included in the search index the next time we rebuild our search index (we rebuild every 2-4 weeks). **After the index is rebuilt your app will be discoverable via Search.**

Comment: I think this is not right. Those needed indexes are after you have an app, you submitted for review and 10 people are using it.  For just seeing your app when you start typing at the top bar of your profile, you just need it to be public.

Comment: You can't get people to use your app and gain index rating unless they have a way to find it. Listing the app in the store searches is not related to this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Anyway, if you think this is not correct open a bug with Facebook and let them check.